# Gradle, How to download .zip file from S3

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm planing to write a custom task as below in gradle to download .zip from the S3

```
task downloadZipFromS3(type: com.amazonaws.gradle.s3.Download) {
  bucket = "${s3.bucket}"
  key = "${s3.key}"
  file = file("your-local-file.zip")
}
```

But not getting any concrete gradle plugin to download the zip. If there is any "standard" plugin or any other way to download .zip files from S3 and save in my project dir?

Comment: use a Java HTTP library, you can import it in your Gradle script

Comment: I used https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task

Comment: would you able to help me with answer to implement it using AWS_ACCESS_KEY/SECRETE_KEY for S3 authentication? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I got it using traditional S3 maven repo plugin download.

I've added zip into my gradle classpath as

```
testLibs("com.myproject:myproject-test-lib:$TEST_LIB_VERSION")
```

And from classpath extracted the cached zip to project dir as

```
/**
 * Extract the 'test-libs' from classpath to project directory.
 */
task unzipTestLibs(type: Copy) {
    from zipTree(configurations.testLibs.find { it.name.contains('myproject-test-lib') })
        .matching { include '**/*.jar' }
    into "$projectDir/libs/test-lib"
}
```

finally, called this task on

```
compileJava.dependsOn(unzipTestLibs)
```